# How to create single object from array of object without overriding the value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to achieve below output?

```
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];
```

Required Output: { a: 1 ,  a: 2 , a: 3 }

The Object.assign overrides the key value and reduces to below output.

```
Object.assign({}, ...arr); // Output: {a:3}
```

Comment: The thing is that all the fields of an object must have unique names. What you're asking is impossible.

Comment: `{ a: 1, a: 2, a: 3 }` isn't valid because objects can't have duplicate properties.

Comment: Yes, I realized - what i needed was a nested object structure so i can have unique key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I should have written on original post -

Array of Object: [{ a: { a: 1 }, b: { a: 2 }, c: { a: 3 } }]

Single Object: { a: { a: 1 }, b: { a: 2 }, c: { a: 3 } }

I was able to achieve it by using below code.

```
const obj = arr.reduce((accum, value) => {
    return { ...accum, ...value }
}, {});
```